# Windows 7 zero key won't work

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm having this really weird issue that I thought I might ask about. On one of my computers the zero key will not work.

The zero key on the number pad works just fine, the right parenthesis works just fine, When I RDP in and try using the remote keyboard I'm still unable to use the zero key, when I use the alt code (ALT+48) it works and when I use On Screen Keboard I'm still unable to use the zero key.

If I open Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator and try to test out the keyboard, it won't recognize the zero key either. However, If I click the start button, click on the search box, and press zero the text will disappear (telling me it is recognizing me pressing the key).

I'm pretty sure it's not the keyboard drivers, since it's not working over RDP or with OSK. But it still could be windows drivers, I'm just not sure which ones.

I'm just curious if anyone has had similar issues and might like to shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Does the problem occur outside of Windows?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq No, It's only within windows. And if I RDP into the system, and then use the system to RDP into another system and press zero, it will show on the third system as 0. So, i feel that it's a corrupted mapping. I'm just not sure how one would go about fixing that.

Comment: Could be the mapping has been messed up somehow. Try SharpKeys - I use that for remapping keys but it should show mappings that can be undone.